# What are all the "Ring of Blood" arena-style quest chains?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm looking for a list of all the PvE arena-style quests in WoW, where you fight an elite monster for a group quest, turn in the quest nearby, and receive a follow-up quest for more of the same: for example, the [Ring of Blood](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=9962) quests in Nagrand or the [Amphitheater of Anguish](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=12932) quests in Zul'Drak.

The [First Rule of Ring of Blood is You Don't Talk About Ring of Blood](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=4958) achievement requires three of these types of quests, but I know it misses a horde-only chain in Grizzly Hills and a chain in Icecrown.

Are there any more PvE arena quest lines? What are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the list of "Ring of Blood"-style quest lines as I know it, in order of suggested level:

- [Durnholde Challenge](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=28643) in Hillsbrad Foothills
- [The Thunderdrome](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=25067) in Tanaris
- [Ring of Blood](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=9962) in Nagrand
- [The Conquest Pit](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=12427) in Grizzly Hills
- [Ampitheater of Anguish](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=12932) in Zul'Drak
- [Battle at Valhalas](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=13214) in Icecrown
- [Crucible of Carnage](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=27868) in Twilight Highlands
- [The Arena of Annihilation](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=31207) scenario<sup>1</sup>

<sup>Note 1: in Mists of Pandaria, Blizzard opted to make most, if not all, new group quest chains into scenarios, including the expansion's "Ring of Blood" quest line</sup>